# How to update a fresh installation of Windows XP SP2 in 2016

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

I have just installed a fresh copy of Windows XP SP2 but it won't install any updates and Microsoft's website seems completely disabled for XP. How can I fix this using only Microsoft's sites?

Comment: You need IE7 or 8 for Windows updates to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Windows XP SP2
2. Optionally download and install SP3 from http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/search.aspx?q=xp%20service%20pack (should be the first result)
3. Optionally download and install Internet Explorer 7

   - https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/f/9/8f9f3096-e6ed-41af-abc3-7dbe0fb2e538/IE7Setup.exe
4. Optionally download and install Internet Explorer 8 (thanks to https://github.com/Explorer09/Ex-pit/blob/master/IE8_XP_Installer_Upgrade/download_links/IE8-XP-x86-direct-links.txt)

   - https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/C/0/CC0BD555-33DD-411E-936B-73AC6F95AE11/IE8-WindowsXP-x86-ENU.exe
5. Install the appropriate patch (thanks to https://www.winhelp.info/windows/windows-xp-slow-during-windows-update/)

   - 32-bit IE6 patch: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40612
   - 32-bit IE7 patch: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40519
   - 32-bit IE8 patch: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40390

When you go to the Windows Update page in IE it should now work instead of giving an error.

Comment: FYI, catalog update only works using Internet Explorer..

Comment: @Moab If you've just installed XP, the only browser you have available is IE.

Comment: How do you know what they have installed?